# Lag compensation with the forth order system

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

The control system below is with lag compensation. The question asks to find `a` and `T` so that the characteristic equation of the system has two conjugated complex poles and damping coefficient $\xi =0.7$ .

[image]

Here is my approach but I'm getting stuck doing that. 
**Step 1**: Find the closed loop gain of the system:
[image]
**Step 2**: From the requirement and because the characteristic is 4th order so I infer that the characteristic has two negative real roots and two conjugated roots.

[image]
[image]

Now I'm stuck on how to solve for this system of equations. There is 5 variables (x1,x2,T,wn, a) as $\xi=0.7$ and 4 equations so one variable can be chosen freely. 
 What parameter and value should I pick for the free variable?

Also I'm wondering if my approach above is correct? If not, how would you solve it?

Comment: I would imagine that the solution may be found using 4th degree linear programming. I imagine that the calculations by hand would run to around 64 A4 pages... Or you can use a Casio CG50 calculator which has built in function up to 6 degrees

Comment: @Rhodie I can use some mathematical software to do that but I kind of don't know how to start. For example, if I pick T first then what values of T should I consider?

Comment: I would set the free variable to 1 and solve from there

Comment: https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf  for ξ=0.7  and 2ξ=1/Q solve T,a for unity gain.